# StateMachineException crossed an AppDomain boundary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nservicebus

My project is a bus that uses NServiceBus.  Recently I started getting an error whenever I start debugging in Visual Studio. 
 The full error is:

```
StateMachineException crossed an AppDomain boundary
Exception occurred in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost, NServiceBus.Host, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling OnStart
```

I don't know if this is an issue with NServiceBus or...what.  So far I haven't found anything by googling around.

Inner exception reveals:

```
{Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException: Exception occurred in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost, NServiceBus.Host, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling OnStart ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No default connection string found in your config file (C:\develop\ironsolutions.bus\IRONSolutions.Bus.InventoryLoaderService\bin\Debug\IRONSolutions.Bus.InventoryLoaderService.dll.config) for the RabbitMQTransport Transport.

To run NServiceBus with RabbitMQTransport Transport you need to specify the database connectionstring.
Here is an example of what is required:

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="host=localhost" />
  </connectionStrings>
   at NServiceBus.Transports.ConfigureTransport.Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a93f853f0c1b9532\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\ConfigureTransport.cs:line 45
   at NServiceBus.Features.Feature.SetupFeature(FeatureConfigurationContext config) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a93f853f0c1b9532\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\Feature.cs:line 203
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(FeatureState featureState, IEnumerable`1 featuresToActivate, FeatureConfigurationContext context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a93f853f0c1b9532\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:line 233
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(FeatureConfigurationContext context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a93f853f0c1b9532\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:line 116
   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in C:\BuildAgent\work\a93f853f0c1b9532\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:line 115
   at NServiceBus.Bus.Create(BusConfiguration configuration) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a93f853f0c1b9532\src\NServiceBus.Core\Bus.cs:line 21
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1 moreConfiguration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 121
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 68
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\WindowsHost.cs:line 30
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Main>b__6(WindowsHost service) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.cs:line 80
   at Topshelf.Internal.ControllerDelegates`1.StartActionObject(Object obj) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ControllerDelegates.cs:line 18
   at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<set_StartAction>b__1(TService service) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper.cs:line 65
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.<.cctor>b__1(ServiceController`1 sc) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:line 35
   at Magnum.StateMachine.LambdaAction`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Magnum.StateMachine.ExceptionActionDictionary`1.HandleException(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter, Exception exception) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionBase`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.State`1.RaiseEvent(T instance, BasicEvent`1 eevent, Object value) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachine`1.RaiseEvent(Event raised) in :line 0
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:line 77
   at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper.cs:line 40
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceControllerProxy.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceControllerProxy.cs:line 47}
```

This is happening after a merge where there were a lot of files changed so it's hard to narrow down what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the connection string not being setup on this line:

```
configuration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>().ConnectionString(config.QueueConnectionString);
```

In my case it was because I had recently done a merge where git incorrectly removed the line that set the QueueConnectionString.

Thought I would post this here in case others ever have this error.